# Ember.js - trouble POSTing to correct endpoint

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember noob here.

I'm trying to make a POST request to a specific endpoint `/v1/orgs/:orgId/events/:eventId` but the app is trying to hit an endpoint at `/v1/events` instead.

I'm wondering how I can modify the path for the POST request so it hits the correct endpoint?

Comment: can you post the POST code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coworker suggesting overriding the default `createRecord` in the adapter, like so:

```
createRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, snapshot, { includeId: true });

    return this.ajax(`${this.host}/${this.namespace}/orgs/${data.event.org}/events/${data.event.id}`, 'POST', { data: data });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the RESTAdapter, you could overwrite [buildURL](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL) according to your needs. You can do this on the application adapter (for all requests) or have specific adapters for resources (`ember g adapter application` or `ember g adapter <resource>`).

Comment: `buildURL`  does look promising. Not really clear to me how to use it for a specific REST method though. In my case I'd only like to use it for POST requests.

Comment: REST implies having the same (base) URL for all request types. If possible change the server's behaviour. That said: you can alway overwrite individual methods in the RESTAdapter that make use of buildURL to behave differently.